# Symfony2 - How to access entity methods dynamically?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to access the Symfony2 entity methods dynamically by calling it's object. 
For Instance:

```
$entityObj = new Products();

// Generic Table Processor to process the table data    
private function tableProcessor($entityObject){

    // how can I get all the Entity methods inside the Products Entity????

    // e.g; $entityObject.getMethods();   // should return all the methods?

    return $entityObject;
}
```

If sorted out! 
I'm sure this procedure gonna help me a lot in writing less code, which otherwise I'll have to write for more than 10-20 entities.

Comment: Will your entities also contain methods that are not getters/setters? For example, are you implementing some interface like **Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface**?

Comment: those are getters/setters for sure and those I want to access dynamically, by keeping in mind that I don't know their names!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the methods in your entities will be getters or setters, you can use **ReflectionObject** to retrieve a list and access them dynamically:

```
$object = new \ReflectionObject($entityObject);

foreach ($object->getMethods() as $method) {
    // $method is a \ReflectionMethod instance
    // invoke it or save its name

    // ...
}
```

Comment: by the way, I can see the method names, but how can I use both get/set methods to access/insert data?

Comment: This way: ``$method->invoke($entityObject, 'argument');``.